# which K3S ports should (not) be exposed on a public interface

Tags: networking, kubernetes, k3s, kubectl

The [K3S documentation explains](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.6/en/installation/requirements/ports/) which ports are required for this kubernetes distribution to work.

What it does NOT explain is, which of these ports are OK to be open on a public interface.

K3S seem to deal with the following ports

```
Master
6443/tcp nodes
8472/udp flannel
10250/tcp kublet (metrics)
10251/tcp controller-manager
10255/tcp kublet (readonly)

Worker
10250/tcp kublet (metrics)
10255/tcp kublet (readonly)
30000-32767/tcp nodeports
```

Given the cluster nodes share their own subnet. It seems to make sense to bind the ports to the subnet interface (instead of the public interface). Unfortunately this is not exactly painless with K3S.

So before jumping through hoops:

**Which of the ports above should be hidden from the public interface?**

**Which of the ports above are secured and maybe even required to available via public interface** (e.g. access to the cluster via kubectl)?

Answer (score 1):

Remember to prioritize security over convenience when deciding port exposure on your k3s cluster.

**Ports that should not be accessible from the public interface:**

- **6443/tcp (Master):** This port is the primary communication port for the Kubernetes API server and should not be directly exposed to the public internet. Instead, consider using a VPN or secure tunneling to access it. That way, you've got a secret handshake before letting anyone in.
- **8472/udp (Master):** You must restrict this port to internal cluster communication. The Flannel networking overlay uses it, and it handles communication between nodes.
- **10251/tcp (Master):** Designed for internal communication, this port is used by the controller-manager and should not be exposed directly to the public.

**Ports that can be safely accessed through the public interface:**

- **10250/tcp (Master and Worker):** This port is used by the kubelet for metric collection and monitoring. While it can be exposed, it's crucial to secure it properly, considering TLS encryption and proper authentication mechanisms to restrict access.
- **10255/tcp (Master and Worker):** Similar to port 10250, it should be secured with proper authentication and encryption if exposed. The kubelet uses this port for read-only access.
- **30000-32767/tcp (Worker):** These ports are used for NodePort services. While you can expose these ports, you must ensure that only necessary services are bound to them and that you have security measures (like firewalls or network policies) in place.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access your cluster with kubectl you only need the port 6443 exposed, anyways as [the official docs indicates](https://docs.k3s.io/installation/requirements#networking), there are some risky ports regarding flannel and vxlan:
[k3s inbound ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1XOa.png)